# Marketing Cloud: Syncronised Data Extension Help

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, data-synchronization

I am a salesforce Developer and do not work with SFMC. We lost our SFMC resource and I have been trying to gen up to cover.

We have 2 Salesforce Objects: RequestType (RT) and RequestResponse (RR). The RequestType is a table that lists email campaigns that we are performing. The RequestResponse is data entered over a data loader which contains: RTID, LEADID, status and other data. This means that, for every email send we do, the data we need is a subset of RequestResponse__c data filtered on RTID.

These object are in SFMC as a Syncronised Data Extension.

I need to send a new email. I have learned that the syncronised data is unavailable to me for sending emails. I created a new DE for this and included a few key columns of data but... How do I get to the data in the SDE so that I can send an email?

Comment: A very straightforward option is to do a SQL query to populate your new DE from sync DE data.

Comment: @JavierDeMauriThis actually helped. Thank you sir.

Comment: Another option could be to build a journey that uses Salesforce data as an entry source listening on record creations or updates in Salesforce.

Comment: why is it unavailable? you may simply need to add ENT. to your data extension name in the ampscript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot select synchronised data extension for email sends.
As people suggested you can use automation studio sql to populate your data extension, make sure the data extension is  sendable and link the subscriber key (your unique identifier) to the corespondent field in the new data extension.

Else you should be able to filter the sync data extension via email studio.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options. Filtering them or querying them if you have to join data from different objects.

If this is the case I would suggest you to install Query Studio, as it will make your life easier. Don't forget to use ent. in your SQL when queryng syncronized DE.

You can read more about Query studio here https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FP3yFUAT